# php contact form reply to sender

Tags: php, email, sendmail

The following code is sending an email from my website, but the email comes from `cgi-mailer@kundenserver.de`, how do i change this to the sender's email address, which i have given the variable `$email`:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $msg = 'Name: ' .$_POST['FirstName'] .$_POST['LastName'] ."\n" 
    .'Email: ' .$_POST['Email'] ."\n" 
    .'Message: ' .$_POST['Message'];
$email = $_GET['Email'];
    mail('me@example.com', 'Message from website', $msg );
    header('location: contact-thanks.php');

    } else {
header('location: contact.php');
exit(0);
}
?>
```

Adding the header `From:` to my mail command seems to allow me to change the email address, but i can't work out how to do it to the variable.

Comment: You may need to supply a `Reply-To:` in the header. Have you had a look in the examples to the [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function?

Comment: I have tried that but it only works for a hard coded email address, rather than a variable. Same as From:

Answer (score 2):

Declare the variable in the headers..

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

**Edit:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $msg = 'Name: ' .$_POST['FirstName'] .$_POST['LastName'] ."\n" 
    .'Email: ' .$_POST['Email'] ."\n" 
    .'Message: ' .$_POST['Message'];
$email = $_GET['Email'];
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail('me@example.com', 'Message from website', $msg, $headers );
    header('location: contact-thanks.php');

    } else {
header('location: contact.php');
exit(0);
}
?>
```

Comment: so mine would look like: &headers = 'From: $email' . "\r\n". ?

Comment: Nope. Just comes through as being from $email, rather than the actual email addresss i entered into the form.

Comment: Still no joy. Now nothing in the from or reply to fields.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$to = "someone@example.com";

$subject = "Test mail";

$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";

$from = "someonelse@example.com";

$headers = "From:" . $from;

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

echo "Mail Sent.";

?>
```

For more reference

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: But that would just send back to an email address harcoded in? I need it to send back to an email address that will change for every person that uses my form..

Comment: The from should be like this: $from = "Someone Else <someonelse@example.com>\r\n"; shouldn't it? Best practice.

Comment: But thats a hard-coded email address. When i reply to the email generated by that, it wont go to the person who filled out the form.

Comment: What do you mean? Look at my code: $email = $_GET['Email']; - so my variable $email should then be able to be used no?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the header

```
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .='Reply-To: $from' . "\r\n" ;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

It should set the sender.

where

```
$from= "Marie Debra <marie.debra@website.com>;"
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$from = $_POST['email'];

$headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
    'From: ' . $from,
    'Reply-To: ' . $from,
    'Return-Path: ' . $from,
);
```